# C++ templated callback bounce function

Tags: c++, templates

I've been trying to come up with a templated function that generalizes the bounce procedure when dealing with C APIs that use function pointer callbacks.

I've mostly figured it out and have a working system, but I'm wondering if there is a way to clean up the final step.

Imagine you have an API that takes a function pointer and a user data pointer. You want to use an instance method as the callback target. This requires a "bounce" function that reinterprets the user data pointer as an instance pointer and calls the method with the rest of the arguments.

The following example code works:

```
#include <cstdio>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int val) : val_(val) { }

    void baz(int v) const
    {
        printf("baz %d\n", v + val_);
    }

private:
    int val_;
};

// Templated bounce function
template<class T, class Method, Method m, class Ret, class ...Args>
static Ret bounce(void *priv, Args... args)
{
    return ((*reinterpret_cast<T *>(priv)).*m)(args...);
}

#define BOUNCE(c, m) bounce<c, decltype(&c::m), &c::m>

// Callback simulator
void call_callback(void (*func)(void *, int), void *priv, int v)
{
    if (func) {
        func(priv, v);
    }
}

// Main Entry
int main()
{
    Foo bar(13);

    call_callback(&bounce<Foo, decltype(&Foo::baz), &Foo::baz>, &bar, 10);
    call_callback(&BOUNCE(Foo, baz), &bar, 11);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically I'm looking for a way to clean up the usage. The macro works but I'm trying to instead find some type of helper function that can just take a method pointer parameter like `&Foo::baz` and deduce all the parameters. Something like a `bounce_gen(&Foo::baz)` that would return a pointer to the actual bounce function.

It has been a fun exercise, but I can't quite get the last piece.

Answer (score 0):

The type of a member function pointer contains the class type and the function signature. So, you can let template function argument deduction handle this for you:

```
template<class T, class Method, class ...Args>
static auto bounce(Method T::*func, T* priv, Args... args) -> decltype((priv->*m)(args...))
{
    return (priv->*m)(args...);
}
```

More convenient might be to either use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or a lambda to completely hide the fact that it is a member function call:

```
template<class Func, class ...Args>
static auto bounceCallable(Func func, Args... args) -> decltype(func(args...))
{
    return func(args...);
}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
call_callback([&bar](int v){bar.baz(v);}, 11);
```

With a lambda, you have a syntax nicer than with `std::bind`, but it comes at the cost of having to repeat the signature.

Comment: The problem is that bounce needs to only take a `void *` user data pointer and arguments. It cannot take a pointer to the member function itself. (I do not control the callback API). In your case, I understand how parameter deduction is working. I instead need something to do parameter deduction and generate the bounce function pointer to pass into the API.

Comment: Ah I see. The same principle applies. Comparing your macro `BOUNCE` and the definition of `bounce` in my answer, the mapping is `c == T`, `decltype(&c::m) == Method T::*` and `&c::m == func`.